# What difference between a thymeleaf and ajax when importing data?

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
          $.ajax({
            url: "",
            method: "",
            data: { },
            success: function(data) {
              ~~~~
            }
          });
```

```
// controller
// ...
model.addAttribute("user", userDTO);
// ...

// html(thymeleaf)
${user.name}
```

When importing data, what is the difference between the above two cases?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example represents a JQuery AJAX method that executes on the JS engine of the Web-browser. The 'success' function will be called **asynchronously** with the response payload and again JS is responsible to do whatever is needed with this data. You can have multiple such asynchronous operations without the need of reloading/refreshing the whole page.

Your second example represents the server-side MVC roundtrip in the backend. This is a **synchronous** operation in the sense that the Web-browser that fires the request blocks until the operation described below completes so that it receives back the parsed HTML.

It follows the MVC paradigm implemented in Spring Framework where [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) is the templating engine representing the **View** (the 'V' in MVC). The `model.addAttribute("user", userDTO)` is tying the **Model** (the 'M' in MVC) so that it can be filled in the placeholders of the template. Both are brought together in the Controller (the 'C' in MVC) that is receiving the front-end request and is responsible for gathering the **Model**s and filling the template returning as a response the parsed final HTML (in fact the Controller in Spring MVC is normally returning the View name and the framework takes care to invoke the registered Template engine). **All this activity happens in the backend**.